# How to make second root category navigation in magento?

Tags: magento

Other than the normal navigation I get when I add subcategories to the main root category, I want to be able to make a new root category, assign subcategories to it and have it display as a separate menu.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

May this can help you :
[Link 1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/managing-root-categories)
[Link 2](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/catalog/creating_and_assigning_root_categories)

To retrieve another root category

```
<?php 
echo '<pre>';
$id=9; 
    $catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $categories = $catagory_model->load($id); // where $id will be the known category id
    if(!empty($categories))
    {
        echo 'category name->'.$categories->getName(); //get category name
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'category image url->'.$categories->getImageUrl(); //get category image url
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'category url path->'.$categories->getUrlPath(); //get category url path
        echo '<br>'; 
    }
    ?>
```

now `$id=9;` is my new root category id.
To retrieve sub categories of these new root category `($id=9;)` below is the following reference code.
Customize it according to your requirements.

```
<?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
 <?php $categories = $this->getStoreCategories() ?>
  <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
    <?php $subcategories = $category->getChildren() ?>
      <?php foreach($subcategories as $subcategory): ?>
        <?php $subsubcategories = $subcategory->getChildren() ?>
         <?php foreach($subsubcategories as $subsubcategory): ?>
         <?php endforeach; ?><!-- end foreach subsubcategories -->
      <?php endforeach; ?><!-- end foreach subcategories -->
  <?php endforeach; ?><!-- end foreach categories -->
```

Comment: you can retrieve root categories by their respective ID's

Comment: This is about replacing the default root category with a different one. I want to use both simultaneously so I can have 2 menus, which was made clear in my question.

Comment: Didn't referred the above comment ? Wait explaining you .Instead of getting angry view updated answer carefully .

Comment: Your comment wasn't there when I commented. I did't get angry, I just made my point clear. I'll check it out later on and get back to you, right now i am experiencing yet another problem in magento.

Comment: The first part literally just echoed the name of the new root (which I don't want), and the second part didn't do anything. Basically I would like it to render the same as the original root category.

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal world you would have found the answer by now, but in case you didn't I modified Nikhil's answer to work for me to basically do what you describe, minus any convenience at all...

```
$id=9; 
$catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$categories = $catagory_model->load($id);
if(!empty($categories))
{
    $cats = explode(",", $categories->getChildren());
    foreach($cats AS $c)
    {
        $cat = $catagory_model->load(trim($c));
        echo '<a href="/'.$cat->getUrlKey().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a>';
    }
}
```

I'm just pasting what I used. The reality is you will have to build the html to make this do whatever you want it to do. If you have subcategories within your loop, you will have to run another fetch in the foreach part. 
I am not familiar with magento enough to know what methods you can run on the $cat object. I did a `print_r($cat)` to examine the object and made a lucky guess that getUrlKey would be available.

Magento... pfft! you'd think ebay would have higher standards than this.