# Magento 3rd level Subcategories Menu

Tags: php, magento, drop-down-menu, categories

I am working on a magento website that has a 2-level (category and subcategory) menu and I would like to add a 3rd level but I don't know how to get it working and I need help.

This is the code I have used to get the 1st and 2nd category levels, how can I get a 3rd level?

```
<div class="left_content">
 <div class="menu">
    <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
    <?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
    <?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
    <?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
            <ul id="menu">
            <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <li class="sub">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
                    <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                    <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                    <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                        <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div class="left_content">
 <div class="menu">
    <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
    <?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
    <?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
    <?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
            <ul id="menu">
            <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <li class="sub">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
                    <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                    <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                    <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                        <ul>
                         <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                <!--sub sub category-->
                                <?php $_subcategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId()) ?>
                                <?php $_subsubcategories = $_subcategory->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                                <?php if (count($_subsubcategories) > 0): ?>
                                 <ul>
                                 <?php foreach($_subsubcategories as $_subsubcategory): ?>
                                 <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subsubcategory) ?>">
                                 <?php echo $_subsubcategory->getName() ?>
                                    </a>
                                 </li>
                          <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                                 <!--sub sub category-->
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now it should be fine to you

Comment: Very nice pie piece of code. You sir deserve too many more upvotes.

Comment: It helped you,@Leonidas .Felt nice . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track .
Just continue with it.
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435468/how-to-make-second-root-category-navigation-in-magento/13450858#13450858)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227838/how-to-display-the-categories-and-subcategories-in-a-tree-format/13099835#13099835)
Hope the above reference link will help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks... But I am not really good with coding and the two links didn't help me too much. I am ok with HTML and CSS but not PHP.

I thought I would be able to add another <ul> with a code to load the 3rd level of subcategories. Would you be able to help me with this code?

I just need to know how I add this 3rd <ul> into the 2nd <li>

Comment: Thanks! Your answer did help, but I still have one problem though. The subcategories that don't have subcategories open a blank dropdown menu. How can I edit it so it only shows another dropdown menu if there are subcategories there?

The website is: http://www.personalproducts4u.co.uk/

Comment: In which category ... can u name it ?