# How to show children's subcategorie's of current categorie in Magento

Tags: magento, children

I am trying to get my big catalog somewhat tablet friendly by offering an selection of tabs with sublevel links for my seperate categories. So if a user clicks a (1st level)head category it needs to display a nr of blocks which hold the picture, description and url of each direct child and a list of all the underlying (3rd level) child categories of the shown (2nd level) categorie. Would any off you guys be so kind to check my code?

```
<?php
   $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
   $_category   = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
   $_categories = $_category->getCollection()

->addAttributeToSelect(array('url_key','name','image','all_children','is_anchor','description'))
     ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
     ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren())
     ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
     ->joinUrlRewrite();
?>

             <?php $children = explode( ",", $this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildren() ); ?>

    <ul class="category-grid">
    <div class="category-list">
        <?php foreach( $children as $child ): ?>
            <?php $_child = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load( $child ); ?>
            <li class="item">
            <a href="<?php echo $_child->getURL() ?>" target="_self"><img title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_child->getName()) ?>" src="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_child->getImageUrl()) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_child->getName()) ?>" /></a>
            <div class="subcategory-title">
        <a href="<?php echo $_child->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_child->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_child->getName()) ?></a>
        </div>
           <div class="description-block"> <?php echo $_child->getDescription(); ?></div>
           <div class="children-links"><?php
           $_helper = Mage::helper("catalog/category"); 
             $rootCat = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
             $current = Mage::registry('current_category');

                 if ($child){
                    //look for anchestor 
                    $parentid = $child->getParentId();
                    $parent = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($parentid); 
                    if($parentid != $rootCat)
                    {   
                        //find the anchestor
                        show_cat($parent,$_helper,$rootCat);
                    }else{
                        //is root 
            $_subcategories = $child->getChildrenCategories();
                echo $_child->getAll_Children(); 
                 if(count($_subcategories)>0){
                            echo '<ul>';
                                    foreach($_subcategories as $_category){
                                        echo '<li>';
                                        echo '<a href="'.$_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category).'">'.$_category->getName().'</a>';

                                            if($child->getId() == $_category->getId()){
                                                $current = Mage::registry('current_category');
                                                if ($current){
                                                    //handle current
                                                    $_current_subcategories = $current->getChildrenCategories();
                                                        if(count($_current_subcategories)>0){
                                                            //the current cat has childrens
                                                            echo '<ul>';
                                                            foreach($_current_subcategories as $_sub_category){
                                                                echo '<li>';
                                                                echo '<a href="'.$_helper->getCategoryUrl($_sub_category).'">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a>';
                                                                echo '</li>';
                                                            }
                                                            echo '</ul>';
                                                        }else{
                                                            //the current cat has no childrens
                                                            $current_parent = $current->getParentId();
                                                            $current_parent  = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($current_parent ); 
                                                            $_current_subcategories = $current_parent ->getChildrenCategories();
                                                            echo '<ul>';
                                                                foreach($_current_subcategories as $_sub_category){
                                                                    echo '<li>';
                                                                    echo '<a href="'.$_helper->getCategoryUrl($_sub_category).'">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a>';
                                                                    echo '</li>';
                                                                }
                                                            echo '</ul>';
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                        echo '</li>';
                                        }
                                echo '</ul>'; 
                            }
                        }
                    }

                                ?>
                </div>  
          </li>
       <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    </ul>
```

Comment: OK, instead of above code I just added: <a href="<?php echo $_child->getChildren()?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_child->getChildren()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_child->getChildren()) ?></a> which will get all subcategories children_id. Any thougts on how to get them to display the correct name/url?

Answer (score 1):

you can this by the below code and also refer link at bottom

you could be go with this

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul class="category">
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php if ($currentCategory->getId() && $currentCategory->getId() == $_category->getId()): ?>
                    <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                    <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                    <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                        <ul class="subcategory">
                            <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                        <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT**

```
<ul class="subcategory">
            <? foreach ($_categories as $_category):?>
                 <? if($_category->getIsActive()):
                      $cur_subcategory=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
                       $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
                       $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_subcategory);
                      ?>

                     <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category)?>"> <?php echo $_category->getName()?></a></li>
                <? endif;?>

         <?endforeach?>

      </ul>
```

Or you can go throw [this Detail documentation](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/display-categories-and-subcategories-in-magento/), i am sure that would be really helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this piece off code just gives all the categories and doesn't filter them in any way like ment as above in my code. I just need to show the 3rd level children of the allready showing (check my code) 2nd sublevel categories.

Comment: @SjorsVoorwinden, use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580970/magento-3rd-level-subcategories-menu also http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-display-other-products-from-the-same-category/ for level 3 category. sure help you. and i would be glad if you will accept my answer.

Comment: I just added <a href="<?php echo $_child->getChildren()?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_child->getChildren()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_child->getChildren()) ?></a> after the childrenlinkds div. This displays only the ID and i need the children's url. Any thougths?

Comment: you have to take from loop http://www.magentobooker.com/magento-get-child-categories just see.

Answer (score 0):

```
// get current category
$current_category   = $layer->getCurrentCategory(); 

// get sub categories of current category
$parent_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($current_category->getId());

// go through each sub category and get their sub categories.
foreach($parent_categories as $child_category)
{
     $child_category_id = $child_category->getId();
     $grandchild_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($child_category_id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tested code for showing sub categories. Just put this code above "Toolbar" code in your custom theme "Magento_catalog/templet/product/list.phtml"

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
$subcats = $category->getChildrenCategories();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$imageHelper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image::class);


if(count ($subcats) > 0)
{
?>
<div class = "sub-cat-div">
    <ul class = "sub-cat-main">
        <?php
        foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
            if ($subcat->getIsActive()) {
                $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
                $_outputhelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
                $subcaturl = $_category->getUrl();

                $_imgHtml = '';
                if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {

                    $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" />';
                    $_imgHtml = $_outputhelper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');


                    echo '<li class="sub-cat-image"><a href="' . $subcaturl . '" class="block-promo" title="' . $_category->getName() . '">' . $_imgHtml . '<span style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9)" class="content bg-white"><strong>' . $_category->getName() . '</strong></span></a></li>';
                }
                else{
                    $_imgUrl = $imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image');
                    $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" />';
                    $_imgHtml = $_outputhelper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');


                    echo '<li class="sub-cat-image"><a href="' . $subcaturl . '" class="block-promo" title="' . $_category->getName() . '">' . $_imgHtml . '<span style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9)" class="content bg-white"><strong>' . $_category->getName() . '</strong></span></a></li>';
                }
            }
        } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php 
}
?>
```